# How to get more than 20 book result from new york time api?

Tags: android, json, api, parsing

I am using new york time api for getting best seller book data. but every time i get 20 result so how to get more than 20 book result.

Url is : https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json?api-key=test 
This url shows that num_result = 29851 so how to get those all JSON data.

Comment: I already used real API key but getting same result. Actually i get first 20 result than after how to get next 20 result @user13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `offset` parameter as a multiple of 20.

https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json?api-key=test&offset=40

Comment: Thank you so much i got more than 20 result @pratZ